# Add reference not showing in vs 2019 on mac

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-mac

It is my first time using visual studio 2019. So, I wanted to use the Clipboard class. In order to use the clipboard class, it looks like I have to add a reference, then import `using System.Windows.Forms`. However, when I right-click on the solution area, then press add reference, it just gives me an empty page.

So, I searched up the problem and people fixed the problem by enabling codelens. However, I found that there were no codelens for mac.

How can I fix the problem with the add reference?
Also, I wanted to know how to import the Clipboard class or if I was doing it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Forms is not supported on macOS, so you won't be able to use that class.

Either you use [Xamarin.Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/clipboard) or use the native [NSPasteboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/mac/app-fundamentals/copy-paste).